# Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular

I have imported FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in my `app.module.ts` file.

But i keep getting the error.

I want to use `ngValue` instead `value` because i want to bind the whole object

So i have

**TS FILE**

```
 sendEmailSuppliersList = [
    {
      guid:1,
      isChecked: true,
      name: 'supplier 1',
      contactName:'person 1',
      contactEmail:'email 1'
    },
    {
      guid:2,
      isChecked: false,
      name: 'supplier 2',
      contactName:'person 2',
      contactEmail:'email 2'
    },
]
```

**HTML**

```
 <tr class="supplierList" *ngFor="let supplier of sendEmailSuppliersList; let i = index">
    <td>
               <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox"
                  [checked]="supplier.isChecked" (change)="onSendEmailSupplierCheck($event)"
                  [ngValue]="supplier"
                 />
    </td>
 </tr>
```

How can i use ngValue on my input type checkbox ?

If i use `[value]` then i don't get any error, but with `[value]` i can't bind my whole object...

Comment: If you need the object in the event handler, why not send it as the argument and bind to `[value]`? Try: `<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" [checked]="supplier.isChecked" (change)="onSendEmailSupplierCheck(supplier)" [value]="supplier"/>`

Comment: Would like to know the reason for binding checkbox `value` with object. Are you try to get the object value when checkbox is checked/unchecked with `onSendEmailSupplierCheck` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngValue` is a property of the `NgSelectOption` directive, which is applied to `<option>` elements. That means it's only defined for `<option>` elements, not `<input>`:

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption.

That being said, as some pointed out in the comments, it doesn't make much sense to bind a whole object to a checkbox control.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you only can check one checkbox at time. If this is true, you can has a variable

```
value:any
```

And don't use "bannana" notation of ngModel else [ngModel] (ngModelChange) in this way

```html
    <tr class="supplierList" *ngFor="let supplier of sendEmailSuppliersList" >
        <td>
           <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox"
                  <!--the checkbox is selected only if value<>null and value.guid is supplier.guid-->
                  [ngModel]="value && supplier.guid==value.guid" 
                  <!-when change, if checked, value is equal to supplier
                     if not checked value is equal null-->
                  (ngModelChange)="value=$event?supplier:null"
           >
        </td>
     </tr>
```

Another option is use "radio buttons", not check-box